# Swift - Check textfield empty or not

Tags: swift

I want to check wheather textfield is empty or not?
 But I'm getting the error `'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly`? What does that mean?

```
guard let email = self.usertxt2.text, self.usertxt2.text?.characters.count != 0  else {
       alert.message = "Please enter your email"
       return
    }
```

Comment: Add more information, pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you defined your "email", you can use the string to count its characters, like so:

```
guard let email = self.usertxt2.text, email.count != 0 else { 
    alert.message = "Please enter your email" 
    return 
}
```

also, you can use the built-in variable

> isEmpty

```
guard let email = self.usertxt2.text, !email.isEmpty else {
    alert.message = "Please enter your email" 
    return
}
```

But I think it's better to validate email using REGEX

```
let email = self.usertxt2.text
guard email.count > 0 else { print("Email is required") 
 return
}
do {
   let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
   if try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegEx,  options: .caseInsensitive).firstMatch(in: value, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: value.count)) == nil {
       print("Invalid email")
   }
} catch {
   print("Invalid email")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`characters` is deprecated in Swift 4. To check empty string, directly use -
`!string.isEmpty`

```
guard let email = self.usertxt2.text, !email.isEmpty else { 
    alert.message = "Please enter your email" 
    return 
}
```

OR

```
guard let email = self.usertxt2.text, email.count > 0 else { 
    alert.message = "Please enter your email" 
    return 
}
```